# How do I set the body and border colors to be the same in a JFreeChart Candlestick chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

There are methods in the CandlestickRenderer class that change the border color of all candles to a desired color, but I need to set all the Up candle borders to green and all the Down candle borders to red. Any advice or example code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this by digging into the `CandlestickRenderer` class source

First, make a subclass

```
public class MyCandlestickRenderer extends CandlestickRenderer {

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int column) {

        //determine up or down candle 
        XYDataset dataset = getPlot().getDataset();
        OHLCDataset highLowData = (OHLCDataset) dataset;
        int series = row, item = column;
        Number yOpen = highLowData.getOpen(series, item);
        Number yClose = highLowData.getClose(series, item);
        boolean isUpCandle = yClose.doubleValue() > yOpen.doubleValue();

        //return the same color as that used to fill the candle
        if (isUpCandle) {
            return getUpPaint();
        }
        else {
            return getDownPaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Then set your chart to use it

```
chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(new MyCandlestickRenderer());
```

Result:

[image: chart]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for and I learned a bit about how the class works. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it to be: `XYDataset dataset = getPlot().getDataset(row);` ? To specify serie index in dataset.